# How to correctly handle multiple privileged MySQL connection accounts

Tags: mysql, database

I have read many posts and articles that state quite clearly that for the best in worst-case damage limitation, MySQL accounts should only be able to do what they're intended to do, and nothing else. This makes perfect sense and so there would be a connection account to my Database that does all the `SELECT`ing of data, and another account that does `UPDATE` and `INSERT` activities, so that if someone does get the compromise by `SELECT`ing data they shouldn't, then they can't *quite* as easily then `UPDATE` that data or `INSERT` etc.

You get the idea.

But, I have various Databases and use accounts to read/`SELECT` data and the this is output to the client page, but often these accounts will need to be updated, small things such as updating when a (website) user logs into their account, or updating some sort of hitcounter or other minor feature. Given the ringfencing of concerns outlined above, I feel it's a bit like using a flood to put out a campfire, to allow `UPDATE`ing (*etc.*) to a privileged MySQL connection simply to say that user Bob logged in last at 4:10pm.

I have been digging on the web for suitable guides, blog posts and articles about how to best structure using multiple MySQL privileged accounts to complete the nessecary work with as minimum a risk of excess privilege as possible, but I have found nothing that has been much use, (mostly because of my wording seems to be attracting articles about setting up website users, or other topics associated with these keywords `:-/` )

I have a few ideas on current approach and wanted a bit of feedback on the best method for doing activities as described in paragraph 2, typically 95% `SELECT`ing, and a few specific instances of `UPDATE`ing, or if any of the following are possible (or on flipside, are very bad ideas)? :

- I currently have seperate PHP connection objects for each connection privilege user. Is this the best approach?
- Could I somehow giving a privilege user access to only update a certain table (or even a certain table column?), as well as `SELECT` from any table? This would be perfect.
- Are using `TRIGGER`s a common approach and would this have any down sides if I created a Trigger (with a privileged user) and then let a `SELECT` user account access triggers?

  - Could I set certain users can only use certain triggers?
- Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Privileges can be set at both database and table level & users can have different privilege levels on each - see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html

Comment: @PaulF that is exactly what I was hoping for, Brilliant, thanks. If you want to pad it out into an answer that would suit me well :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL allows for users to have different privileges set both at database and individual table levels. The documentation on the GRANT (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) syntax gives an example of setting all privileges to a user on one database while only select access to a table in another database.

Privileges can even be set for specific columns (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html#grant-column-privileges) in a table & also for stored procedures (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html#grant-routine-privileges).